# Ideals prime to the conductor in the ideal class group of an order

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field, $\mathcal{O}_K$ its ring of integers and $\mathcal{O}$ an order in $K$.
I'm going through the proof for the formula linking the cardinality of the class group $Cl(\mathcal{O})$ to that of the class group $Cl(\mathcal{O}_K)$. I'm following the proof given [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/conductor.pdf) by Keith Conrad. At the end of page 11 he makes the following statement:

> From the proof that $Cl(\mathcal{O})\longrightarrow Cl(\mathcal{O}_K)$ is surjective, we can represent each ideal class in $Cl(\mathcal{O})$ by an ideal $\mathfrak{b}$ of $\mathcal{O}$ which is relatively prime to the conductor $\mathfrak{c}$

and the fact that $Cl(\mathcal{O})\longrightarrow Cl(\mathcal{O}_K)$ is surjective is Theorem 5.1, which uses the fact that the same statement is true in the maximal order $\mathcal{O}_K$. However, although I can easily prove the statement for $\mathcal{O}_K$ using unique factorization and the Chinese Remainder Theorem, I can't really see how this implies that the same statement is true for $\mathcal{O}$. From the proof of Theorem 5.1 I can see that every coset of the kernel of the map $\psi:Cl(\mathcal{O})\longrightarrow Cl(\mathcal{O}_K)$ contains a class verifying the statement (just take $\mathfrak{a}$ in any class of $Cl(\mathcal{O}_K)$ such that $\mathfrak{a}$ is prime to the conductor and consider $\mathfrak{a}\cap\mathcal{O}$), and if I could use the explicit description of $\ker(\psi)$ which Conrad gives soon after that statement, then the statement would follow easily, as is done [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342246/representative-in-ideal-class-group-coprime-to-the-conductor) on MathOverflow. However this description depends on the statement itself, so we can't use it.
So I guess I'm probably missing some trivial step, but I can't really see that, hence even hints are really appreciated.

**Edit:** The statement in the question is also mentioned by Pete L. Clark [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72213/ideal-classes-and-integral-similarity), in the last 3 lines. The reference is Neukirch, but I can't find this claim in his book. Moreover I'm wondering wheter this question is more appropriate for MathOverflow, since I've only seen this claim in MO posts so far.

**Edit 2:** I've just found another claim which implies the aforementioned statement. It is Proposition 20.13 from [these](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral2015.pdf) notes by Pete L. Clark:

> Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain, $I$ a fractional ideal of $R$ and $J$ a nonzero integral ideal of $R$. Then there exists $a\in I$ such that $aI^{-1}+J=R$.

This is stated for Dedekind domains, but it seems to me that the proof given in the notes should still work even if $R$ is a non-maximal order, provided that we assume $I$ to be invertible. Indeed, using the same notations as in the original proof, there should be finitely many distinct prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}_1,...,\mathfrak{p}_r$ containing $J$, because if $\mathfrak{p}\supseteq J$, then $\mathfrak{p}$ is minimal on $J$, since $\dim R=1$, and in a noetherian ring there are finitely many minimal prime ideals on each ideal. Moreover $I\mathfrak{p}_1\cdots\mathfrak{p}_n\subsetneq I\mathfrak{p}_1\cdots\mathfrak{p}_{i-1}\mathfrak{p}_{i+1}\cdots\mathfrak{p}_n$ for all $1\leq i\leq r$, for otherwise, using the invertibility of $I$, we would find $\mathfrak{p}_1\cdots\mathfrak{p}_n=\mathfrak{p}_1\cdots\mathfrak{p}_{i-1}\mathfrak{p}_{i+1}\cdots\mathfrak{p}_n$, and considering that these are comaximal ideals, this implies $\mathfrak{p}_i\supseteq\mathfrak{p}_j$ for some $j\neq i$,  which is clearly impossible. Then the rest of the proof should work without any modification.

This is quite different from the proof I had found for the maximal order, since that proof relied too much on unique factorization to be extended to the non-maximal case. Although this should solve my question, I'm not closing it since I'm still interested in knowing if there is a way to prove the statement in non-maximal orders as a consequence of the fact that the same property holds true in the maximal order, which is what K. Conrad seemed to suggest in his notes. Moreover it would be nice if someone could confirm that what I wrote above is correct.

Comment: As to your Edit2: I agree that the proof you mention goes through for Noetherian domains of dimension 1, provided $I$ is invertible. Invertibility is also needed to see that $I\mathfrak{p}_1\cap (I\mathfrak{p}_2\cdots\mathfrak{p}_s)\subseteq I\mathfrak{p}_1\cdots\mathfrak{p}_s$.

Comment: @MatthévanderLee Thanks for your feedback. I agree that we need invertibility to see that $I\mathfrak{p}_1\cap(I\mathfrak{p}_2\cdots\mathfrak{p}_s)\subseteq I\mathfrak{p}_1\cdots\mathfrak{p}_s$, but I didn't mention that in the post because it's exactly the same thing we would do in the maximal order. Anyway, do you have any idea on what K. Conrad meant in his notes?

Comment: No, I am afraid not. Incidentally, Corollary 3.7 in K. Conrad's notes does not appear to be valid as stated: if $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ are $\mathcal{O}$-primes (relatively prime to the conductor) that lie over the same rational prime $p$ and are of the same residue class degree, one has $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{a}\cong\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{b}$, but not necessarily $\mathfrak{a}=\mathfrak{b}$.

Comment: @MatthévanderLee There is a much more detailed explanation of a more general version of Corollary 3.7: it is Theorem 8.9 in [these](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/idealfactor.pdf) notes, again by K. Conrad. Here it's clearly stated that given a simple $\mathcal{O}$-module $M$, there is a unique prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $\mathcal{O}$ such that $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p}\cong M$ **as $\mathcal{O}$-modules**: I think the problem with your example is that $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{a}\cong\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{b}$ is an isomorphism **of fields**, which doesn't imply that there is

Comment: also an isomorphism **of $\mathcal{O}$-modules**. Indeed, if there is an isomorphism **of $\mathcal{O}$-modules** then it follows that $\mathfrak{a}=\mathfrak{b}$ by comparing annihilators in $\mathcal{O}$. And the latter is the case of Corollary 3.7, since Jordan-Holder theorem gives isomorphisms of $\mathcal{O}$-modules.

Comment: Ah, of course, that is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original way I had written up what you asked about was rather garbled, but now I have updated the file. The task of representing each ideal class for an order by an ideal relatively prime to the conductor of the order is now a special case of the first part of Theorem 5.3. The proof of that has now been changed to an argument given by Will Sawin [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420465/an-omission-in-k-conrads-notes-on-the-conductor-ideal?noredirect=1#comment1080045_420465), which is similar in some ways to the argument you describe.